# Utilisation du mot "Abilité"

Tags: choix-de-mot

Est-ce que le mot "Abilité" existe dans la langue française ?

Par exemple, puis-je dire : "Je te félicite pour ton abilité à terminer ce projet" ?

Cf . : [définition - abilité (Sensagent)](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/abilit%c3%a9/fr-fr/).

Comment: Ce dictionnaire collaboratif ne me paraît pas fiable. *Abilité* n'est pas un mot français, pas même un mot rare.

Comment: J'assume tu veux dire "habilité". http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/habilit%C3%A9/fr-fr/ (_aptitude de pouvoir faire_)

Comment: Aujourd'hui, le lien mène à _-abilité_ comme suffixe. Il s'agit d'une forme de pourriture de lien. Il faut probablement lier à : https://web.archive.org/web/20180221084749/http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/abilit%C3%A9/fr-fr/ où on a « pouvoir ; n.f. ».

Answer (score 8):

J'ai vu le lien référencé et le contenu de cette page m’inquiète ! 
Je vais vérifier si le mot, tel qu'il est écrit dans ce site existe en français ou non…

Le français a « emprunté » du latin  deux mots qui dérivent de « **habilitas** » et qui s'écrivent presque de la même façon : « **habilité** » et « **habileté** », à savoir des paronymes.

Si j'ai bien saisi ce que tu veux dire, le mot recherché serait « habileté » :

> Je te félicite pour ton habileté à terminer ce projet

donc en ajoutant un *h* au début et avec un *e* suivant le *l*.

Cependant, c'est pas dans les règles de l'art : c'est tiré par les cheveux !
L'usage mentionné me semble un anglicisme qui fait allusion à « ability ».
En effet en anglais « ability » coïncide avec « capacité » ou « aptitude ».

> ability to carry out a research project

*Ability* signifie « avoir les capacités requises pour mener à bien une tâche ou un projet », mais en français cette nuance n'est pas respectée à 100%.

> Nous avons été éblouis par l'habileté avec laquelle le chef de projet a résolu le mal-entendu.

Ici *habileté* est un substantif (c'est pas un adjectif) qui est employé plutôt pour dire « adresse », « doigté » et « dextérité » ; ici, il ne s'agit pas de préciser si le chef de projet a résolu ou non (donc s'il était capable ou non) mais on insiste sur **le comment des choses** (manière: comment ça a été fait ?) : le chef de projet a eu le **talent** requis pour résoudre un problème ou pour mener à terme le projet et c'est justement ce talent qui est mis en exergue par le mot « habileté ».

À ne pas confondre avec l'autre mot « habilité » (c'est un adjectif) qui s'emploie presque uniquement dans un registre soutenu et professionnel, surtout **législatif** et qui signifie « **capacité juridique à faire quelque chose** » ou « **être titulaire d'un pouvoir, de prérogatives, permettant l'accès à tel ou tel statut** » :

> une autorité habilitée à prendre la décision

ou

> habilitation à diriger des recherches scientifiques

Tu peux visiter [la page de l'OLQF qui traite de ce sujet](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2035) pour plus d'informations.

Note :

J'ai cherché dans les dictionnaires qui sont à ma disposition (Larousse, Hachette) et j'ai pas trouvé de mot avec l'orthographe mentionnée par l'OP: je présume qu'il s'agit d'une erreur qui a glissé suite à l'absence d'une bonne veille/modération sur le site en question.

Comment: J'aimerais ajouter que "habileté" dans ce sens est très peu usité (dans mon expérience), et sera compris dans son deuxième sens "dextérité". capacité et aptitude sont de meilleures suggestions à mon avis.

Comment: @Jhyn,tout à fait,habileté s'emploie plus fréquemment pour "dextérité" que pour "aptitude"

Comment: Inquiétant dictionnaire en effet !

Answer (score 3):

*« <strike>Abilité</strike> » n’existe pas.

Le mot que tu cherches est [habileté](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/habilet%C3%A9).

Si [habilité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/habilit%C3%A9) existe dans l’acception que tu souhaites, il est vieilli (je découvre personnellement son existence). Le participe passé d’« [habiliter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/habiliter) », par contre, est toujours d’usage, mais il ne signifie pas la même chose.

Comment: *Capacité* ou *aptitude* étaient probablement les sens recherchés. « L'habileté à terminer quelque chose » c'est quand même quelque chose d'assez étrange.

Comment: J’y ai songé et c’est vrai que la tournure semble étrange, mais en parlant de « capacité » ou d’« aptitude », on met l’accent sur plus que sur le *fait* d’avoir rempli son objectif. En parlant d’habileté, il me semble que l’on met l’accent sur la *manière* employée pour y être parvenu. D’une certaine manière, vanter la capacité, c’est dire « je n’étais pas certain que tu étais capable » ; vanter l’habileté, c’est dire « je n’étais pas certain que la tâche était réalisable ».

Answer (score 0):

Avec un "h" devant, ce sera encore mieux.
http://cnrtl.fr/definition/habilit%C3%A9